# How to build a simple card flip effect with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to update the following code which should remove/add class on click of `.card` panel not on mouseleave which it does currently.

> http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/9884/

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flipped');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You could try having an if statement to check whether the element has the class `flipped` and if it does, remove it, else add it to the element.

Comment: your event working properly please check your css of flipped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the class is present and then decide conditionally what to do (add or remove a class as desired):

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    var card = $(this).find('.card');
    if (!card.hasClass('flipped')) {
        card.addClass('flipped');
    } else {
        card.removeClass('flipped');
    }             
    return false;
});
```

If you want to use different buttons to flip the card you could use something like this:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
   var card = $(this).find('.card');
   if (!card.hasClass('flipped')) {
      card.addClass('flipped');
   }
   return false;
});
$('.exit').click(function(){
  var card = $(this).closest('.exit').parents('.card');
  card.removeClass('flipped');
  return false;
});
```

This will flip back when the closing button on the back is clicked. It will get the close button and tries to find a parent with class ***.card*** to remove the ***.flipped*** class

```
 <div class="flip"> 
    <div class="card"> 
        <div class="face front"> 
            Front
        </div> 
        <div class="face back"> 
            <div class="exit">x</div>
            Back
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I created a fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8n3gokua/1/

Comment: Thanks. I am using your code because I want to remove the class by clicking a div not to use as toggle

Comment: @MarkusHayner But this code has exactly the same result as using `toggleClass`. Adding the class if not already there, and removing it if it is already there is by definition toggling.

Comment: Yes but I am looking to remove the class from a button like when you have a div `$('.exit').removeClass('flipped');` You know what I mean?

Comment: any idea how to do this? i don't want to click over all card class to remove the class

Comment: Where do you want to click instead?

Comment: Have a look on this http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/9894/ an let me know if you have any idea how to remove the class by clicking that x

Comment: @DenisThomas Downvote changed to upvote after your edit :) Good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
 $('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .toggleClass just like bellow:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
});
```

You can learn more from [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.flip').bind("click mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```